# Computing the gradient with respect to a metric $g$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I was reading Ali’s answer in this post

> https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301865/are-there-vector-fields-which-are-gradients-with-respect-to-one-metric-but-not-a

and I am not sure how did he computed the gradient of $f=\frac{-1}{2} (49x^2-10xy+y^2)$ with respect to the metric

$g=5 \ dx \otimes dx- dx \otimes dy - dy \otimes dx + 5 \ dy \otimes dy$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient vector can be expressed as

$$ \nabla f = g^{k\ell}\: \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\: \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\ell} $$

where the metric $g^{k\ell}$ is the matrix inverse of the metric

$$ g_{k\ell} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & -1\\-1&5 \end{bmatrix}$$

thus

$$g^{k\ell} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{5}{24} & \frac{1}{24}\\\frac{1}{24}&\frac{5}{24} \end{bmatrix}\text{ .}$$

Doing the first steps, we see that

$$ \nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{5}{24}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{24}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\ \frac{1}{24}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{5}{24}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \text{ .}$$

Going ahead and computing the first row,

$$ \frac{5}{24}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{24}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{5}{24}(-49x+5y) + \frac{1}{24}(5x-y) = -10x+y$$ which is clearly the first component of the vector field $\vec{X}$ from the other post.